# Performance in select rows where condition is a percentage of match with a set

Tags: python, pandas, performance, parallel-processing, execution-time

Given this sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['id1','id2','id3'],
                  'col2':['name1','foobar','name3'],
                  'col3':[{'am', 'e1', 'me', 'na'},{'ar', 'ba', 'fo', 'ob', 'oo'},{'am', 'e3', 'me', 'na'}]})

    col1    col2    col3
0   id1     name1   {na, e1, me, am}
1   id2     foobar  {ar, fo, ba, oo, ob}
2   id3     name3   {na, e3, me, am}
```

The target is to subset `df` with all rows that satisfy a matching threshold of intersection of two sets.

**My solution:**

```
def subset_by_intersection_threshold(set_1, set_2, threshold):
    intersection = len(list(set_1.intersection(set_2)))
    union = (len(set_1) + len(set_2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection / union)>threshold
```

With a jaccard function and `pandas apply` filter by a threshold all rows that match a condition (0.4 of matching in this example) .

```
set_words=set(['na','me'])

df[df.col3.apply(lambda x: subset_by_intersection_threshold(set(x), set_words,0.4))]
```

As im feeling this solution is a little brute force mode, I open this question in order to learn more efficient alternatives considering execution time.

## Adding the benchmark scores performed in my personal laptop:

From slower to faster:

```
%timeit df.col3.apply(lambda x: original(set(x), set_words, 0.4))  # 74 ms per loop
%timeit df.col3.apply(lambda x: jpp(x, set_words, 0.4))            # 32.3 ms per loop
%timeit list(map(lambda x: jpp(x, set_words, 0.4), df['col3']))    # 13.9 ms
%timeit [jpp(x, set_words, 0.4) for x in df['col3']]               # 12.2 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance by a factor of ~2x by avoiding unnecessary `list` creation and `float` / `set` conversion. For an extra boost, index via a list of Boolean values, constructed using a list comprehension. As often the case, `pd.Series.apply` may underperform a regular loop inside a list comprehension.

```
def original(set_1, set_2, threshold):
    intersection = len(list(set_1.intersection(set_2)))
    union = (len(set_1) + len(set_2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection / union)>threshold

def jpp(set_1, set_2, threshold):
    intersection = len(set_1 & set_2)
    union = (len(set_1) + len(set_2)) - intersection
    return (intersection / union) > threshold

set_words = {'na', 'me'}

df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df.col3.apply(lambda x: original(set(x), set_words, 0.4))  # 74 ms per loop
%timeit df.col3.apply(lambda x: jpp(x, set_words, 0.4))            # 32.3 ms per loop
%timeit [jpp(x, set_words, 0.4) for x in df['col3']]               # 23.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: I didnt expected to reduce more than a half of execution time! awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on structure of your problem and whether you want to run the test several times, you could reshape the data into boolean values, and then do the jaccard computation somewhat vectorized:

```
# Create bool table
    na     me     am     e1     ar     fo     ob     oo     ba     e3
0   True   True   True   True  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True   True  False
2   True   True   True  False  False  False  False  False  False   True
```

Might be infeasible (if too many different values) or too slow (setup takes very long), but here's the code for it:

```
df_bool = df.col3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({s: True for s in x})).fillna(False)

# set_words as bool
sw = df_bool.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x in set_words).values

# intersection / union > 0.5
res = (df_bool & sw).sum(axis=1) / (df_bool | sw).sum(axis=1) > 0.4

# setup code (run once)
%timeit df.col3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({s: True for s in x})).fillna(False)  # 

%timeit [jpp(x, set_words, 0.4) for x in df['col3']]                    # 14.4 ms per loop
%timeit (df_bool & sw).sum(axis=1) / (df_bool | sw).sum(axis=1) > 0.4   # 10.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: at the moment the df has 50K rows, the function is performed every time a name has to be found in a column.

Comment: If you have lots of queries (`set_words`) but `df` doesn't change at all, this could be faster when the setup time is amortized over the many queries. On top I'm sure the setup could be sped up considerably as well.